# GWT setting iframe dimensions programmatically from the inside

Tags: gwt, iframe, jsni

I have an iframe that contains GWT code. I'd like from that code to dynamically change the iframe dimensions.

I'm trying the following:

```
Element iframe = we start from some element inside the iframe;
while (!iframe.getTagName().toLowerCase().equals("iframe")) { // get embedding iframe
    iframe = iframe.getParentElement();
}

iframe.setAttribute("style", "height:100px;width:100px;");
```

It doesn't work. Somewhere in the middle I reach a null parent before getting to the iframe.

How can I change the iframe dimensions from GWT that runs within the iframe itself? I don't mind if its a JSNI-based solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it. If the document inside the iFrame is in your domain, and the document which includes the iFrame is in a different domain, the security mechanism will prevent you from making any changes from one to the other.